# What happens when I add a tag which doesn't exist to my favorite tags?

Tags: support, tag-watching

I notice that I can add a tag which doesn't exist on Stack Overflow to my favorite tags. What happens when I do this? Does it mean I have created a new tag? But I don't have the privilege to create a new tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing happens. Your favorite tags list is simply that - a list. What you type in there has no effect on anything else on the site, and all it does is let a client-side script highlight any questions that match that tag. If the tag doesn't exist, then it won't highlight anything.

Comment: For example, I add "wordp" which doesn't exist on SO to my favorite tags. And I can click the "wordp" icon which links to the tagged questions list. Does it mean nothing happen too?

Comment: It will just take you to an empty page for a nonexistent tag.

Comment: Indeed. You can go to the question list for any non-existent tag. (e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bundt-cake) and it'll just show you an empty list rather than return a 404.